# How to add text as content in Rectangle C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following rectangle, which is filled with color. i want to add some text inside in middle of the box. please suggest some solution.

```
var rect1 = new Rectangle
{
     Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
     Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
     Width = 150,
     Height = 100,
     VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top,
     HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
 };
 Grid.SetRow(rect, 0);
 TGrid2.Children.Add(rect1);
```

Basically i want to make a drag and drop feature. where rect1 will be dragged over rect2; which will only have border color and transparent Fill-body and on drop replaces rect2 with dropped rect1.
Thats why i made a rectangle and now trying to figure how to add text in rectangle as content in center, similar like a button.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you absolutely must use a rectangle, you could fake it!

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Hi there" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: very nice idea, for my situation for now. will work. but problem is, i must provide width & height for rectangle to show the border, and if i need a longer unknown text, This won't help me later.

Comment: @Bsienn use the width and height of the grid to control the rectangle and text. the Margin on the textblock ensures that it does not overlap the rectangle border.

Comment: i entered a longer string and the text came out from the rectangle, from ur suggestion i get that i must do rect.width = text.width. but for now its working for my current task

Comment: @Bsienn use the `TextWrapping` property on the `TextBlock`

Answer (score 7):

Replace the `Rectangle` by a `Grid` or a `Border` and put a `TextBlock` inside.

Comment: let me try ur suggestion, be back soon. thanks for reply

Comment: I am wondering this same issue as im using rectangles for touchscreen animation and need to add labels inside of them. At this point should i just be using commands such as regular buttons, but can i transform it?